# Is my alpha messed up?

Tags: rendering, materials

I used some of the shaders from the tutorial "[How to make the Iron Man Nanotech effect in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eI2p6hNi6w8&t=340s)". The shader is controlled by an *Empty* object and should make the model fully transparent when the *Empty* is far away. The closer the *Empty* has moved the more of the model is revealed by the "materialize" effect.

So the hands, legs, and eyes have their own material with the effect shader (a node group) and are supposed to be fully transparent when the *Empty* is not near. But they are always visible no matter where the *Empty* moves. It looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

It's not really identical. How do I fix this?

Here's the link to the file: [Blend file (google drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZzO4p00PdjQAyNRivtIUgJns4K6j3LnD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It might help if you could provide your .blend file for us to take a look at - https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: The tutorial is about making a transition of the material disappearing/appearing, and your material looks like in middle of that transition... So it looks like it works...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZzO4p00PdjQAyNRivtIUgJns4K6j3LnD/view?usp=sharing
 heres a google drive link

Comment: What is the actual problem? The eyes are not transparent? A brief description of what you expect is helpful to answer your question. And you can add a link directly to your question. So it's immediately visible. If there are many comments only the first few and the up-voted comments are shown and your link can get hidden.

Comment: I highly recommend giving the materials proper names! This saves you a lot of confusion. The body material uses the output of the shader group for the *Alpha* of the *Principled BSDF* directly and it works as expected. The eye mask does not use the shader group at all. The *Alpha* value is here always 1. And in the materials of the hands and feet, you mix the output of the shader group with the *Alpha* of the image texture which is probably 1=no transparency (textures are not included). The result is a 0.5 to 1 = always semi-transparent to fully visible. Fix: remove the *Mix RGB* nodes.